# Accessing FFMPEG installed above public_html webspace

Tags: php, .htaccess, video, ffmpeg

On a shared server with ffmpeg installed above the webspace.  Example: /home/username/ffmpeg/ffmpeg   which is the full address all the way down to the executable.

The problem is that php cannot find ffmpeg using the -verson option. We tried using mod rewrite to a php file in the public_html webspace which then includes the ffmpeg address above the webspace. But that did not work.

I have never dealt with ffmpeg installed this way, its always been installed in /usr/bin/ or /usr/local/bin .

1. is there a htaccess or php ini command to tell php where ffmpeg is installed?
2. how does php suppose to access ffmpeg installed in this way, it is installed as an alias?

Thanks so much :)

Comment: Just use the full path?

Answer (score 1):

As php and ffmpeg are separate things, there's no guarantee that your host will allow php to run ffmpeg, however here are some things you can try:

You can check if web server's user (which php runs as) can "see" any ffmpeg executables in its path by running:

```
<?php echo shell_exec("which ffmpeg"); ?>
```

If the output is empty, ffmpeg isn't in the path of the web server's user. In this case you still might be able to run it, if you know the path of the executable.

Also if you run:

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

That will tell you if php is running in safe mode. If it is, your web host may have locked down php's ability to do potentially dangerous things such as executing shell commands.

Comment: Thanks rangfu, i will check things out and update this question asap.  ;)

Comment: Im back, i wanted to update you on this..  There is no info showing for the [which] test. Safe mode is not on. They are running CGI/fastcgi which i know is known for breaking ffmpeg.  The only thing i found to try is to add the ffmpeg executible to the cgi-bin folder.  That did not work either.   And the direct address does not work as well.  /home/username/ffmpeg/  or /home/username/ffmpeg/ffmpeg .   I also created a folder in the local domain called local_ffmpeg and put a copy of the exe file in there as well and then added that folder to the htaccess rewrite. Still nothing any ideas?  :)

Comment: I also just found out that it is NOT the binary version but the portable version of ffmpeg that was installed, so i hope that helps in the answer here.

Comment: I would verify that the full path definitely exists and is visible to php by doing eg. "<?php echo file_exists("/home/username/ffmpeg/ffmpeg") ? "yes" : "no"; ?>" (replacing this example path with the one you know). If you get a "yes", please let me know how you're trying to call/use ffmpeg.

Comment: Unfortunately we had to advise them that they needed to get a vps or dedi with root access.  Even when they loaded ffmpeg in the public webspace php could not find it.  We were calling ffmpeg as normal exec('ffmpeg....  we did try shell_exec as well.  We tried using include in the php file itself only to receive a parse error from the ffmpeg exe file of invalid syntax.   The  only portable version of ffmpeg that i was able to find was a windows version, and why the host would install that on a linux server i have no idea. Anyway i wish i had more but we have closed our ticket for the customer.

Answer (score 0):

Change Permission of binaries files (ffmpeg.exe and ffprobe.exe) to 0744.

See image sample here: [image: permission change image]